# ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and binary targets

Tags: python, sklearn, deep-learning

Olá.
Eu estou criando uma rede neural para categorizar alguns dados. Basicamente a rede neural vai me dizer de qual molécula é.

O meu código é este:

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, StandardScaler

#%%
base = pd.read_csv('fotoacustica-mol.csv')
atributos = base.iloc[:, :-1].to_numpy('float64')
classe = base.iloc[:, -1].to_numpy()

scaler = StandardScaler()
atributos = scaler.fit_transform(atributos)

encoder = LabelEncoder()
classe = encoder.fit_transform(classe)
classe = np_utils.to_categorical(classe)

#%%
def neuralNetwork():
    classificador = Sequential()
    classificador.add(Dense(units=4, activation='relu', input_dim=4))
    classificador.add(Dropout(0.2))
    classificador.add(Dense(units=4, activation='relu'))
    classificador.add(Dropout(0.2))
    classificador.add(Dense(units=3, activation='softmax'))
    classificador.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                          metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
    return classificador

#%%
classificador = KerasClassifier(build_fn=neuralNetwork, epochs=10,
                                batch_size=10)

resultados = cross_val_score(estimator=classificador,
                             X=atributos, y=classe,
                             cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
```

Porém ocorre este erro quando vai rodar a outra porção do banco de dados

```
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and binary targets
```

Não entendo o que seja. Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

O erro indica que você está passando mais de uma label por amostra (por exemplo, uma lista ou array com mais de um elemento). Compare os valores que estão sendo fornecidos no `fit` na variável `classe` (da primeira porção e segunda porção dos dados). Certifique-se que eles tenham o mesmo `shape`.

Comment: A minha classe de atributos tem o shape (806, 4) enquanto que a minha classe tem (806, 3). Verifiquei isso tudo mesmo assim o erro persiste.

Comment: Consegui rodar fazendo apenas a categorical (0, 1, 2), porém não é ainda como quero implementar.

Comment: O problema não é relacionado com os atributos e sim com a classe. Você tem duas opções, out trabalha com o Y.shape=(806, 1) e atribuinto valores [0] ou [1] ou [2] ou com o Y.shape=(806, 3) e [1, 0, 0] ou [0, 1, 0] ou [0, 0, 1] (considerando que você não está trabalhando com multi label)